# FTP deployed Microsoft MVC3 website. POST protocol ISN'T working. GET protocol IS working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, web-config, web-deployment

I am developing a website using Microsoft MVC3, and have built it upon the default MVC3 Application template. It accesses an external database and works on localhost.

I have deployed it to a shared server I rent from storminternet via the publish tool using ftp method (storminternet do not yet support web deploy), and it runs well. It accesses the database okay and get requests work fine.

However, any form that submits via POST protocol returns page not found error 404 (this is on actions where I have asserted [HttpPost]).

Storm internet assure me that POST and GET are allowed by default, and since the helpdesk are not developers, I'm unsure who to turn to. I don't have an excellent understanding of web.config, although I can read and understand xml and see what's going on by reading through and googling. I have tried adding the protocols to the root web.config, and I think I might be barking up the wrong tree.

Has anyone else had this problem, or might anyone know how to help me?

To replicate my error, my site is here... 213.229.125.117/$sitepreview/ase-limited.com/Dev (sorry it isn't blue. The dollar gets parsed to % something)

and the quickest route to a POST request is to click 'Add Building' at the top of the left-hand side and then click 'Save' at the top of the dialogue box.

Any help will be gratefully received. I've been stuck on this for days without luck.

Best Regards
Nick

STOP-PRESS-STOP-PRESS-STOP-PRESS-STOP-PRESS-STOP-PRESS-STOP-PRESS-STOP-PRESS-

It turned out to be a known issue with sitepreview. Switching to the proper domain sorted everything.

Comment: I get a 404 error when I click on your link.

Comment: Hiya Darin. Yeah, the parser changed the $ symbol into a %something code. I have had to edit the link. It copy+pastes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that you have some 404 javascript errors when performing your AJAX requests. For example you have a request to:

```
http://213.229.125.117/$sitepreview/ase-limited.com/BuildingManager/Employees/2
```

instead of:

```
http://213.229.125.117/$sitepreview/ase-limited.com/Dev/BuildingManager/Employees/2
```

Notice how `/Dev` is missing. That's because in your javascripts you have hardcoded your urls instead of using url helpers to generate them. For example you wrote something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/BuildingManager/Employees/2',
    ....
});
```

which works fine on localhost because you don't have a virtual directory name but doesn't work when you deploy on your server because now the correct path is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Dev/BuildingManager/Employees/2',
    ....
});
```

For this reason you should absolutely never hardcode urls like that.

And when I try to POST the form in tries to post to http://213.229.125.117/Dev/BuildingManager/SaveBuilding which seems a very weird url as it is missing the whole beginning. Once again: never hardcode urls. Always use url helpers.

Comment: Yeah, I learned that mistake the hard way. I spent this morning wrapping URLs in @Url.Content("~/fghfg/hfdgh/fgh"). I missed that one. How did you get http://213.229.125.117/Dev/BuildingManager/SaveBuilding ? I get http://213.229.125.117/$sitepreview/ase-limited.com/Dev/BuildingManager/SaveBuilding . I don't know if it helps, but I'm using Chrome web browser

Comment: Unfortunately not. I fixed that URL in the JavaScript though, so many thanks for that. I would have missed it! My forms still aren't posting though, and the URLs are correctly formed via helpers. I've been using FireFox too. Only problem with it is that it runs a little slower, but then my laptop is hardly a beast of a machine.

Comment: ...one more thing. I just tried through Firefox, and the URL generated is http://213.229.125.117/$sitepreview/ase-limited.com/Dev/BuildingManager/SaveBuilding which is different to what you got. Do you still get the shortened one?

Comment: @user1271898, when I submit the form, FireFox POSTs to `http://213.229.125.117/Dev/BuildingManager/SaveBuilding` which redirects to `http://213.229.125.117/$sitepreview/ase-limited.com/Dev/BuildingManager/SaveBuilding` which itself ends up with 404. So you are not posting to the correct url. COuld you show the code for this form in the view as well as any javascript that you might have if you are using AJAX to submit it?

Comment: Oooh! ..and yes certainly. The code that generates the URL is: 

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveBuilding", "BuildingManager", new { param_Building_ID  = Model.Building.Building_ID }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
... 
} ...So, do I need to wrap the Controller string in @Url.Content("BuildingManager")? ...My AJAX forms are similar, except I use Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm.

Comment: Hmm, it appears the helper doesn't know what the head of the Url should be. Do you know where I set this? Is it something in web.config?

Comment: I don't quite know what I'm looking for. Do you know if I need to set the URL header within the web.config or another file under httpdocs, or is this an issue with a setting elsewhere on the server?

Comment: Ok. I've been told that by storm internet that this is a known issue with sitepreview, and that it should work when I switch to the proper domain name aka ase-limited.com/Dev/ but I'm having issues with permissions and Plesk at the moment and not sure what is going wrong. Hopefully I'll have found the answer by the end of today